# Gradle build failed with unsupported class file major version 64 in Flutter project

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I encountered an issue while building my Flutter project with Gradle. The build failed with the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/mishalhaneef/Documents/flutter/Zartek/blind_crushes/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/mishalhaneef/.gradle/caches/7.4.1/scripts/a7jtzc7d8e1ht64fuhmylehgj).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using    │
│ for Gradle.                                                                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│ To fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter doctor      │
│ --verbose`.                                                                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                     │
│ /Users/mishalhaneef/Documents/flutter/Zartek/blind_crushes/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper │
│ .properties to be compatible with that Java version. See the link below for more information on  │
│ compatible Java/Gradle versions:                                                                 │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                                │
2
│                                                                                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I'm using Flutter for my project, and it seems that there is a compatibility issue between the Gradle version used and the required Java version.

I have already checked the Java version used by Flutter by running flutter doctor --verbose and noted the version displayed. I also updated the Gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to be compatible with the Java version.

Despite these steps, the error persists. I tried running the build with `--stacktrace` for a more detailed trace, as well as using `--info` and `--debug`options for additional log output, but it didn't provide further insights.

Answer (score 0):

In 'android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'
Change distributionUrl

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

In 'android/build.gradle',
Change 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:****' to

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your gradle version to higher one.